# How to fix spoolss.dll missing error on window 7 64bit?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, compatibility, dll

I am trying to run old window program (lieroai.exe) on fresh instal windows 7 64bit. I am getting the message:

```
This application failed to start because spoolss.dll was not found.
Re-installing the application may fix this problem.
```

The file is present in the system (c:\windows\system32). I am logged in as ordinary user (if that matter).

Is there a solution?

Comment: Is the file present in `C:\Windows\SysWoW64` ? If the old application is 32-bits, it will only be able to load 32-bit DLLs.

Comment: @DarthAndroid Do you think that copying it there can be enough?

Comment: The program you are trying to run isn't even the correct extension for a file that can be executed.

Comment: @IvanH - Copying the file will not work.  You should already have a 32-bit and 64-bit copy of the file if its installed by default.

Comment: @Ramhound:The name is lieroai.exe. You are right. After copying there is 0xc000007b error.

Comment: Liero? the worms? That brings back memories!

Comment: Is there a recommended solution? I have the same problem!